# Using postcss-loader after css-loader

Tags: webpack, css-loader, css-modules, postcss-loader

I am using CSS modules with webpack css-loader, then I bundle them with mini-css-extract-plugin. 
Here is how my config looks like:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
      MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      {
        loader: "css-loader",
        options: {
          modules: true,
          localIdentName: "[name]-[local]_[hash:base64:5]",
          imports: true,
          importLoaders: 1
        }
      },
      "postcss-loader"
    ]
  }
```

For some reason (see comments section) I would really like to apply postcss-loader not to every individual .css file, but to the whole bundle. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Every css module incapsulates in itself all the media queries the component should respond to.
And I would like to use `css-mqpacker` to combine them together.
In fact everything works in my current config, but css-mqpacker works within one particular .css file. And what I want is to apply postcss stuff to the whole bundle

Answer (score 4):

Thank you all for trying to resolve my problem. After all I've found the solution. I do not use `postcss-loader` any more, but instead I use `OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin` like this:

```
new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
  cssProcessor: postcss([CSSMQPacker]),
}),
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is probably sole hint all over the internet. Im now using your solution because of sharing `postcss-css-variables` between files. I have just one problem... when using `postcss-loader` I can correctly get warnings like `variable --xyz is undefined and used without a fallback` but when switching from `postcss-loader` to your solution via plugin warnings are completely swallowed so I can not detect possible issues. Can you help me please with this?

Comment: Next problem is not working source map and also building time during watch is slow because it is processing all files again and again not just one modified. So I think I should avoid going this way.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referencing your other CSS with **@import**?

I have been trying to do the same thing for merging duplicate CSS selectors. I've had moderate success using *postcss-import*. It will combine all of your imports so you can process it with *postcss* before *css-loader* bundles it all up.

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
                modules: true,
                localIdentName: '[name]-[local]_[hash:base64:5]'
            }
        },
        {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
                plugins: [
                    require('postcss-import'),
                    require('css-mqpacker')
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately, this can lead to asset pathing issues as *postcss* knows nothing about webpack's path resolving.

You can work around that with aliases.

```
require('postcss-import')({
    resolve: id => id.replace(/^~?(@example-alias)/, path.resolve(__dirname, './src'))
}),
```

Hopefully this helps. I too would like a simpler solution with *css-loader*. 
Ideally: **import & combine** (css-loader) > **postcss** > **bundle** (css-loader)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a webpack plugin to run on the css bundle and apply you postCss plugin on it.

You can check as a reference some plugin that i've wrote:
https://github.com/wix-incubator/extract-tpa-style-webpack-plugin/blob/master/src/index.js#L71